# Select data in date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in which I want to select data from a column where the data is a date. The problem is that the data is a mix of text and dates.

This bit of SQL only returns the longest text field:

```
SELECT MAX(field_value)
```

Where the date does occur, it is always in the format xx/xx/xxxx

I'm trying to select the most recent date.

I'm using MS SQL.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a column (or perhaps a new table) that holds the date values with the data type `date` and from now on always use that column for the dates. After that the query you have will work just fine.

Comment: If the column "*is a date*" how can it have a mix of dates and text? What is the data type of the column in question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I worded it wrong. The column datatype is varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using [`ISDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) and [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DateTime, MaybeDate))
FROM (
  SELECT MaybeDate
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ISDATE(MaybeDate) = 1) T
```

You could also use `MAX(CAST(MaybeDate AS DateTime))`. I got in the (maybe bad?) habit of using `CONVERT` years ago and have stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without a conversion error:

```
select max(case when isdate(col) = 1 then cast(col as date) end)  -- or use convert()
from . . .
```

The SQL statement does *not* specify the order of operations.  So, even including a `where` clause in a subquery will *not* guarantee that only dates get converted.  In fact, the SQL Server optimizer is "smart" enough to do the conversion when the data is brought in and then do the filtering afterwards.

The only operation that guarantees sequencing of operations is the `case` statement, and there are even exceptions to that.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using PATINDEX in WHERE clause.

```
SELECT PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', field_value)
```

Problem with this approach is you really are not sure if something is date (e.g. 99/99/9999 is not date). 
And problem with IS_DATE is it depends on configuration (e.g. DATEFORMAT).
So, use an appropriate option.